# Mean Value Theorm on Wikipedia why $c \in (a,b)$?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

From [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#cite_note-Comenetz2002-5) 
[image]

By IVT (as in the proof given on the wiki page) we can only deduce $c \in [a,b]$, where is it implied that $c \in (a,b)$?

P.S. How do I scale the image down in size?

EDIT: Here are my thoughts. I claim that if equality holds in their proof of the equation, 
$$ mI \le \int_a^b f(x) g(x) \, dx \le M I . $$

then we are reduced to either $f(c)=m$ for some $c \in (a,b)$ or $I=0$. Wlog, 
$$ mI = \int_a^b f g \, dx \Rightarrow \int_a^b (m-f)g \, dx $$ 
Hence, we have $(m-f(x))g(x) = 0$ a.e. on $(a,b)$. If $m \not= f(x)$ for all $x \in (a,b)$, then we must have $g(x)=0$ a.e., hence $I=0$. In this case, $c$ can be arbitrary.

Comment: I think the image scaling happens automatically. Alternatively, you're welcome (and encouraged) to transcribe the image using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: The proof proves that $c\in(a,b)$, since that's what Rolle's theorem gives you.

Comment: @5xum If you read the proof on on the linked wikipedia article, they actually do pick a $c\in [a, b]$, not in $(a, b)$.

Comment: This $c$ produced here need not be unique.  Are you claiming that if there are at least two values $c_1$ and $c_2$ that work then either $I = 0$ or any $c \in (a,b)$ works?  Are you trying to show that $c \in (a,b)$ always and we could not have $c = a$ except in the trivial case?

Comment: Yes, I think that if $c=a$ or $b$ then we are at the trivial case. Otherwise we can pick $c \in (a,b)$. Is this correct?

Comment: @CWL: See the posted example.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the following proof:

Let $F(x):= \int_{a}^x f(t) dt$ for $x \in [a,b]$. Since $f$ is continuous, $F$ is differentiable and $F'=f$ on $[a,b]$. Since $\int_{a}^b f(t) dt=F(b)-F(a)$, there is, by the Mean value Theorem, a number $c \in (a,b)$ such that

$\int_{a}^b f(t) dt=F'(c)(b-a) =f(c)(b-a).$

Comment: Thanks, can we extend this to the general case with integrable function $g$? (Actually, this was what I wanted. -  what do you think of my argument?)

Answer (score 1):

There is another non-trivial possibility where $\int_a^b g(x) \, dx \neq 0$ and $c$ can take the value $a$ or $b$ but not every value in $(a,b)$.

Consider the (continuous) function $f(x) = \left(1 + \frac{\sin x}{2} \right)^{-1}$ and the (integrable, positive) function $g(x) =1 + \frac{\sin x}{2} $ defined on the interval $[0,2 \pi]$.

We have

$$\int_0^{2\pi} f(x) g(x) \, dx = \int_0^{2\pi} g(x) \, dx =2\pi.$$

Hence,

$$\int_0^{2\pi} f(x) g(x) \, dx = f(c)\int_0^{2\pi} g(x) \, dx, $$

for exactly three points $c = 0, \pi, 2\pi$ where $f(c) = 1$.

From this example we see that it would not be incorrect to state as the conclusion of the mean value theorem that there exists at least one $c \in [a,b]$ such that

$$\int_a^b f(x) g(x) \, dx = f(c) \int_a^b g(x) \, dx.$$

Comment: RRL, sorry what did I state that contradicts this? Maybe I miscommunicated.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $a<b.$  You have shown that if $f(c)=m$ then $c$ can be any member of $[a,b].$

Similarly, if $f(c)=M,$ show  that $c$ can be any member of $[a,b].$

If $f(c) \not \in \{m,M\}$  then there exist $c_1,c_2$ in $[a,b]$ with $f(c_1)=m<f(c)<M=f(c_2).$ ..... So by def'n of $m$ and $M$, since $f$ is continuous there exists $ c'$ strictly between  $c_1$ and $c_2$ with $f(c')=f(c).$ Now $c'\in (a,b).$